# Unable to pin notes and add tables in Notes, High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, notes.app

So, two of the key features of High Sierra is that its Notes app has the ability to pin notes and add tables. However, both of the actions are inactive. Is there some trick on using them?

I'm using Macbook Air 13' 2017, High Sierra 10.13.1

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you’re signed in to more than one iCloud Mail account on your iOS device or Mac and have notes syncing turned on, you can only use the new Notes features with your primary Apple ID account.

https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204987

Add some notes to the On My Mac location (enable from Notes Preferences) — if you're able to use the features, it looks like the location/account you're using doesn't support those features.